# How to derive $\mathbb E(e^X)$ if $X$ is normally distributed?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, expected-value

Assume that $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. How do I derive $\mathbb E(e^X)$? Note I'm not asking for a mere answer, but an approach how to solve it. I end up messing with integrals, and change of variables, and it's not working.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}$Have you tried completing the square in the integral, to reduce it to a Gaussian integral? By the way, first you can just work out $M(t):=\E\left[e^{tZ}\right]$ for $t\in\Bbb{R}$, where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Once you work this out, you can use that $\E\left[e^X\right] = e^\mu M(\sigma)$ (because $X$ is equal in distribution to $\mu+\sigma Z$). This makes the integral that you need to calculate nicer.

Comment: You can also see this page: [Calculating moment generating function with normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140583/calculating-moment-generating-function-with-normal-distribution).

Answer (score 7):

As **always**, $$\mathbb E[f(X)]=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\mu_X(\,\mathrm d x),$$
where $\mu_X$ is the measure on $\mathbb R$ induced by $X$. In the case where $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma ^2)$,
$$\mathbb E[f(X)]=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}\,\mathrm d x.$$