# Expected value of a simil lognormal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let X be $N(\mu, \sigma)$. 
I know that $E[e^X]=e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$ (log-normal expectation).

But what about the distribution of $E[e^{-x}]$. I tried to create a square on the exponential but the sign minus is making it hard. With E[$e^{x}$] the proof was straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we have $$\Bbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right] = e^{t\mu + \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}.$$ (See [Calculating moment generating function with normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140583/calculating-moment-generating-function-with-normal-distribution) for a proof.)

Set $t=-1$ to get the answer you desire.