# Finding moment generator function, when the mean and variance are known

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Let's say I have this random variable $X$ with $E(X)=\mu$ and $Var(X)=\sigma^2$. How can I find the moment generating function? I know that $M'(0)=E(X)$, and that in general $M^{(k)}(0)=E(X^k)$.
So I'd force $M'(0)=\mu$ and that $M''(0)=E(X^2)=\sigma^2+\mu^2$.
How can I proceed?

Comment: You have not been given enough information to find the generating function. You will likely need more information , such as the distribution of $X$.

Comment: That's true I missed an information. X has normal distribution. so?

Comment: Ah, in that case, you might want to look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140583/calculating-moment-generating-function-with-normal-distribution). Your formulas are right, but constructing the moment generating function from the derivatives to get an explicit formula is quite difficult.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you, you have been precious!

Comment: You're welcome, I will now close this as a duplicate of the attached question.