# How can it be derived? (Law of the unconscious statistician)

Tags: statistics

On [pg. 7](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Erjones/bus864/readings/Rennie%20and%20Baxter%20%281996%29%20Financial%20Calculus.pdf) of *Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing* by Martin Baxter & Andrew Rennie, it states:

> [image]

**My Understanding**

I did try to derive this picture. But I don't understand how this outcome that is $S_0\exp(\mu -0.5\sigma^2)$
is derived. Could I get any hint of it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book did you take this from? It might be helpful to the other users if you made this reference in your question.

Comment: @Laufen Google says it may be from Martin Baxter & Andrew Rennie's _Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing_, Cambridge University Press, 1996, page 7 [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=3_4gAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22Law+of+the+unconscious+statistician%22+%22tells+us+that+the+expected+stock+price%22&source=bl&ots=46Kz0i6i-W&sig=ACfU3U3E2TQRHtpKEK3G3bWomrWFcYUXdQ&&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0muXboajvAhUqAhAIHRHaB7QQ6AEwAHoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=%22Law%20of%20the%20unconscious%20statistician%22%20%22tells%20us%20that%20the%20expected%20stock%20price%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that $Y=e^X\sim \text{Lognormal}$ thus its mean is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

If you want to do all the calculation with the gaussian distribution, it is not difficult; try, it is a good exercise

Answer (score 1):

The stated law is the all-too-familiar definition of $\Bbb E(h(X))$. Since$$X=\ln S_T-\ln S_0=\ln\tfrac{S_T}{S_0},$$we have $S_T=S_0e^X$. This function of $X$ has mean $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{S_0}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{S_0x-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma)^2}$, [which evaluates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822020/moment-generating-function-of-gaussian-distribution) to $\Bbb E(S_T)=S_0e^{\mu+\tfrac12\sigma^2}$.